# Как правильно вывести Template Tag

Tags: django, шаблоны

```
def count_callbacks():
    data = CallBacks.objects.filter(read=False).count()
    return {'data': data }
```

есть у нас тег шаблона, как вывести в шаблоне или не выводить при логике

```
{% if count_callbacks != 0 %}
Count = {% count_callbacks %}
{% endif %}
```

Спасибо!

Comment: {% count_callbacks as cc %}
{% if cc != 0 %}
Count = {{ cc }}
{% endif %}

Comment: Too many positional arguments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Зарегистрируй тег как assigment_tag

```
@register.assigment_tag
def count_callbacks():
    data = CallBacks.objects.filter(read=False).count()
    return {'data': data }
```

Comment: [assignment_tag deprecated since version 1.9, simple_tag should be used instead.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-template-tags/#django.template.Library.assignment_tag)